# what's a good way to determine a global maximum in an arraylist

Tags: java, algorithm

In my program i have a loop which computes integer values and put it one after another into an arraylist.
The higher the computetd integer value is, the better it is.
Now i want to continue to compute until it seems to be that there will not come any better integer value. That is, when the computed integer decreases over a range, or it does not change anymore. I'm thinking of, comparing the current computed value with the last x (how much value do i have to concern?) If it is always smaller or equals than any of the last x elements I stop computing. But with this strategy i have no guarantee that this is the global maximum, but just a local....

What is a good strategy to do that?

**EDIT:**
I know that there can't be a guarantee to find the global maximum.
But i know a little about the behaviour of the function:
The more values i have already computed the more unlikely it is that the global maximum will appear.

Comment: Without any knowledge on the function, it is impossible to guarantee a global maximum. Though the suggested approach IMO is still too simplified and naive.

Comment: if the input values are more or less randomly, you cannot know when the maximum (or near) comes

Comment: What is the logic used for computing integer values? What is the distribution like for these values (input and output)?

Comment: Do you have performance issues with `Collections.max()`? Call it once after computing integers is done.

Comment: @jlordo You missed the issue here. The issue is how to determine "when to stop", not how to find the max from a given data.

Comment: @amit: I voted your first comment. In that case the question is extremely vague, as we know nothing about the function or it's purpose. My point was how to determine the global maximum after finishing the function.

Comment: thanks for your replies, i have edited my question. i'll try it that way: for each newly computed value i compare it with say 30 % of the previously computed values. if I can determine a decreasing trend i can asume that this will be the (approximated) global maximum....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems that you need to assume some heuristics to assess when to stop. Since you cannot say "I stop now, as I found my max", you can proceed in one of the following fashions:

- Keep current maximum and compare the next value with the current one, if it is smaller, increase the counter. If the counter reaches X (your parameter) you stop
- Use a probablity distributionfunction which has probability of 1 at 0, and 0 at +inf. this can be tailored to your liking. Then, you simply increment the number of seen values, or a counter of smaller values, and using that counter you estimate the probability using that function. If  prob < X (your param again) you stop.

Hope this gives you some idea

Answer (score 1):

[Reservoir Sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling). Store the values in a smaller array *A* which represents random x samples from the computed integer values. Now for a range of computed values, you can compare each with the values in array *A* and if you find a decreasing trend, you can stop. This would guarantee that you are dealing with global max rather than local.

Comment: what values must the array A contain? Just some (random) values from the already computed values?

Comment: The Pseudo code of how to store the values in Array A is mentioned in the wiki link given in the answer.